In LWC how to do a Pill with a Subtitle
I want to create a Pill in a Lightning Web Component, or something that looks like a Pill, with a subtitle in it.  Consider the lighting-record-picker component.  It allows additional fields to be displayed below the main label.  I don't see options on lighting-record-picker to add a subtitle line.
Below is an example from a VF page that uses SLDS to get the Lightning look.  I'm wonder what's the best Lightning Web Component to get the same look.


You can utilize the LDS of the Pill component and build the component as you need.
Below is an example:
HTML::
<template>
    <span class="slds-pill slds-pill_link">
        <span class="slds-pill__icon_container">
            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="Account">
                <svg class="slds-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account"></use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Account</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="slds-pill__action" t561258-databinding_databinding=""
            title="Test"><span class="slds-pill__label" t561258-databinding_databinding="">Test</span> <br />
            <span class="subtitle" t561258-databinding_databinding="">subtitle subtitle subtitle</span>
        </a>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon slds-pill__remove" title="Remove" onclick={handleRemove}>
            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
            </svg>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Remove</span>
        </button>
    </span>
</template>

JS::
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomPill extends LightningElement {

    @api label = 'Test';
    @api subtitle = 'subtitle subtitle subtitle';

    handleRemove() {
    // Handle the remove action
    }
}

CSS::
.subtitle {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #666;
}

Output::

